# Could not find a required file

Tags: docker, create-react-app

I'm trying to run docker container with create-react-app App. App works fine and here's how my dockerfile looks like.

```
# base image
FROM node:12.2.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR ./

# add `//node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH ./node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache  dependencies
COPY package.json ./package.json
COPY ./build/* ./public/
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.0.1 -g 

# start 
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

When I run docker im getting error

```
> my-app@0.1.0 start /
> react-scripts start

Could not find a required file.
  Name: index.js
  Searched in: /src
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-07-14T08_29_30_761Z-debug.log
```

has anybody have any idea?

Comment: you didnt copy the project, and install the dependencies, and build the project.

Comment: Can you give me idea where and from and how can i copy ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`npm start` is for webpack - which serves you as the dev server. you are still using directly the `src` files, not the minified `build` (`dist`), which will only be used on production.

```
#Dockerfile.dev:

# base image
FROM node:12.2.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR ./

# add `//node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH ./node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json ./package.json

#use the minified build file for production, not now - npm start is for development.
#COPY ./build/* ./public/ 

#install dependencies:
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.0.1 -g 

#copy your project files: (also bad for development, use volume(https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) instead)
COPY . . 

# start 
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Answer (score 1):

(This builds on @EfratLevitan's answer, but is a little more production-oriented.  Their answer will be better if you want to use Docker as a core part of your development flow.)

If you have a working Webpack setup already, its output is static files that can be served up by any Web server.  Once you've successfully run `npm run build`, you can use anything to serve the resulting `build` directory – serve it as static content from something like a Flask application, put it in a cloud service like Amazon S3 that can serve it for you, directly host it yourself.  Any of the techniques described on the [CRA Deployment page](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment) will work just fine in conjunction with a Docker-based backend.

If you'd like to serve this yourself via Docker, you don't need Node to serve the `build` directory, so a plain Web server like [`nginx`](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) will work fine.  The two examples from the image description work for you here:

```sh
# Just use the image and inject the content as data
docker run -v $PWD/build:/usr/share/nginx/html -p 80:80 nginx
```

```sh
# Build an image with the content "baked in"
cat >Dockerfile <<EOF
FROM nginx
COPY ./build /usr/share/nginx/html
EOF

# Run it
docker build -t me/nginx .
docker run -p 80:80 me/nginx
```

The all-Docker equivalent to this is to use a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) to run the Webpack build inside Docker, then copy it out to a production Web server image.

```
FROM node:12.2.0-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json yarn.lock .
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.0.1 -g 
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

In this model you'd develop your front-end code locally.  (The Webpack/CRA stack has pretty minimal host dependencies, and since the application runs in the user's browser, it can't depend on Docker-specific networking features.)  You'd only build this Dockerfile once you wanted to run an end-to-end test with all of the parts running together before you actually pushed out to production.